# ¿Cómo puedo capturar la firma? asp.net core mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Hola tengo una pequena duda sobre como puedo capturar la firma de una persona en ASP.net Core mvc C#.

Ejemplo tengo una Rotativa donde se pide la firma al final, me gustaria saber si es posible implementar una funcion que deje capturar la firma y guardarla para posteriormente ser insertada en el documento pdf.

Gracias

Comment: Suena a que sí se puede hacer, pero necesito más datos de lo que estás haciendo, dispositivos que usas, etc... se me ocurre a bote pronto que haciendo una captura de pantalla y guardando el archivo como una imagen, luego tienes que añdir esa firma (imagen) a donde quieras

Comment: El proyecto esta pensado para ser usado en web mobile, yo tambien creo que se pueda pero no se exactamente como puedo desenvolver la idea, yo me imagino algo como un bitmap donde pueda dibujar y despues guardar ese dibujo en sql para despues insertarlo en el pdf

Comment: Podrias mirar por favor el [tour] y tambien [ask].. esta pregunta es lo que se considera basada en opiniones y podria terminar cerrada.

Comment: @KevinWalch, no te puedo poner como hacerlo ya que yo lo tengo hecho en otra plataforma totalmente diferente, pero mirate este webcomponent que igual te sirve: https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad , con esto puedes obtener un png que lo guardes en la base de datos y despues lo insertas en el pdf, asi es como lo hago en mi aplicacion.

Comment: Muchas gracias @JeroniChamorro.

Comment: Para capturar una firma y guardarla en un documento pdf, tienes que hacer que alguien firme y después guardarlo en un documento pdf.

Comment: eso, o realmente la gente 'importa' la firma, es decir, añade una imagen con la firma

Comment: que es una Rotativa?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini es un port de [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) a asp mvc o asp core si no me equivoco

Answer (score 3):

La forma para capturar una firma es por medio de un `canvas` en `html 5`, pero vas a necesitar algo mas que `asp.net core` ya que esta funcionalidad se implementa del lado del cliente y se envia al servidor por medio de `ajax`

[A minimalist example of using Html5 Canvas to save signature as image using Web API](https://manasbhardwaj.net/minimalist-example-using-html5-canvas-save-signature-image-using-web-api/)

En este caso no define en el html un canvas directamente, sino que se ayuda con la libreria

[signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad)

por eso veras que define

```
<div class="panel-body" id="signature-pad">
<div>
```

es el panel donde se firma

Despues envia la imagen de la forma al servidos

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Signature data)
{
    byte[] photo = Convert.FromBase64String(data.Value);

    //resto codigo
}
```

La idea es enviar la imagen serializada como `base64`, por eso hace uso del `toDataURL()` para obtener esa serializacion

```
dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL().replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
var data = JSON.stringify(
                   {
                       value: dataURL
                   });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/signature",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("Done!");
    },
    error: onWebServiceFailed
});
```

y enviarla por `ajax` al servidor